# Is there a word that includes laptops, desktops, Macs and PCs, but not mobile devices

Tags: synonyms, technology, concision, computing

I want to write the sentence "I am creating an app which is intended for use on **laptops, desktops, for both MAC and PC**". Is there a single word I can use in place of what I have bolded?

They are all computers, but "computer" includes smartphones and calculators.

Comment: Smartphones and calculators are NOT computers, are you kidding me!

Comment: @Ricky A smartphone is not a computer? Yet they're used to browse the internet, create and store documents and other files, send email, etc. etc. I'd sooner argue that a smartphone is not a phone.

Comment: No.  "Laptops" span a range from desktop-sized units to ones that are closer to a "pad", so there is no clear dividing line.

Comment: Not a single word, but the best attempt I've seen is the distinction between 'large-screen' or 'large-display' devices and 'small-screen' or 'small-display' devices. For your use, I think I would avoid further ambiguity by using a negative: "...is not intended for use on small-screen devices".

Comment: @pyobum: Take my word for it. A smartphone is a silly toy for amateurs.

Comment: One approach would be to specify by operating system:  Windows and OSx.

Comment: @Ricky We should probably take this to chat, but I'm curious as to how you define "computer" (and why a smartphone doesn't qualify as one). [computer:](https://www.google.com/search?site=&source=hp&ei=JA6bVs-TCcW50AStuKzQCA&q=computer+definition&oq=computer+definition&gs_l=mobile-gws-hp.3..0i131j0l4.3579.6266.0.6739.4.4.0.1.1.0.271.830.0j2j2.4.0....0...1c.1.64.mobile-gws-hp..0.4.697.3.zUa1IVkBizo) an electronic device for storing and processing data, typically in binary form, according to instructions given to it in a variable program

Comment: @pyobum: When someone tells you they're going to buy a computer, is the smartphone the first thing that comes to mind? _Really_?

Comment: I disagree with the assertion that they are all computers. They may all be computers in *function*, but they are not all *perceived* as computers. When someone says "computer software," nobody is thinking "app". The social consciousness does not lump mobile devices in with what we call a "computer." A "computer" is someone's desktop or laptop, maybe tablet, depending on the tablet, but not their phone, their calculator, or any of their other wireless devices. It is not unlike the word "oven."  A microwave may be an "oven," but nobody thinks "microwave" when told to put something in the "oven."

Comment: Incidentally, if you want to create an "app" that you want to be understood as NOT for mobile devices, then don't call it an "app."  An "app" relates to a mobile device.  When talking about computers, we use the longer word "application" or the word "software" or the word "program."  The word "app" specifically connotes that it is for a mobile device.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman good comment.  This question largely hinges on perception.

Comment: My thinking is mostly in line with what Benjamin said regarding perception vs. function. From a consumer perspective, a smartphone and a computer are two different products. I would never go to the computer section in an electronics store expecting to find smartphones. But in the general sense of what a computer does (function/capability), I absolutely consider smartphones to be computers. Perhaps a company will try to introduce the term mobile/portable computer a few years down the line. One final thought: ENIAC was a computer; smartphones can now do much more. It's just a matter of scale.

Comment: @Ricky When someone tells you they’re going to buy a computer, is a multi-rack mainframe computer the first thing that comes to mind? I’d be very surprised if it were. And yet there can be no doubt whatsoever that mainframe computers are computers. Whether something is the first thing that comes to mind is irrelevant. The only criterion by which smartphones and tablets are not computers is subjective association. By any objective definition, they are computers. So are calculators, modern TVs, cars (at least their, well, computers), robots, and a host of other things we don’t normally call it.

Comment: I think the horse has left the barn.

Comment: @HotLicks Thinking is good for you.

Comment: @Ricky: When someone tells you he saw a bird in the tree outside his home, is an ostrich or a penguin the first thing that comes to mind?  And yet they are birds.

Comment: @Scott That's the point I was trying to make earlier.

Comment: @Ricky: No, it’s the point Janus Bahs Jacquet made two days ago, and it’s *the **opposite*** of the point you were trying to make. If you believe otherwise, please explain, in plain, simple, direct language, what you are saying. Here; I’ll start: smartphones and calculators (etc.) *are* computers, for the reasons presented by pyobum and Janus.

Comment: @Scott: Of course they're computers. Technically. However, when someone tells you he or she is going to buy a computer, they don't mean a phone or a pad. They mean a laptop. When it's anything else, they'll qualify it: "I'm going to buy a desktop, I think." Eventually, when laptops are phased out, buying a computer will once again mean buying a desktop. My TV is a computer. My external sound card is a computer. My electronic piano is a computer (my real piano is not). Your car has a chip in it. As does every turnstile in the subway. And every cash register at the supermarket. So what.

Answer (score 6):

The word is PC.

> **Personal Computer**
>
> a computer designed for use by one person at a time.
>
> [google.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=Personal+computer&oq=Personal+computer&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=personal+computer+definition)

A desktop is a PC.

> **desktop computer**
>
> A desktop computer is a **personal computer** designed for regular use at a single location on or near a desk or table due to its size and power requirements.
>
> [google.com](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define+desktop+computer+is+a+personal+computer)

A laptop is a PC.

> **laptop**
>   /ˈlæpˌtɒp/
>   noun
>
> 1. a **personal computer** that is small and light enough to be operated on the user's lap Compare palmtop computer
>      [reference.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/laptop)

A Mac is a PC (sorry but it's true).

> **Personal Computer**
>
> a compact computer that uses a microprocessor and is designed for individual use, as by a person in an office or at home or school, for such applications as word processing, data management, financial analysis, or computer games.
>   Abbreviation: PC.
>
> Contemporary Example:
>
> In early 1977, they founded Apple Computer which quickly became one of the dominant forces in the **personal-computer** field.
>
> From the Archives: Steve Jobs on the Birth of the Mac
>   Tom Zito
>   October 5, 2011
>
> [reference.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/personal-computer)

When people say Mac vs. PC they're really saying Mac vs. Not Mac.

PC, or personal computer, is a generic term.  No one owns it.  Thus it can suffer from a lack of promotion.

Every desktop and laptop Apple has ever produced has been a PC.  They didn't all use the same CPU or operating system as the IBM clone PC that still dominates the market share but they were all personal computers.

Why doesn't everyone know this?  Because Apple spent a lot of money convincing people they weren't just buying an overpriced PC.

For a long time Apple used motorola CPU's that were not compatible with intel/amd x86 CPU's used to make clones of IBM's PC.  Thus Apple PC's were not compatible with the windows operating system and couldn't run it's applications without emulation.

Since Apple was the only one making these motorola computers if you didn't call them Apple or Mac computers but simply PC people would assume you meant the x86 based ones based on context since IBM clone PC is a mouthful.

But now Apple uses intel to make it's PC's so you can't say there is any difference other than branding.  You can install windows on an Apple PC and it will run natively, without emulation.

So PC means personal computer.  This can include Apple PCs or not depending on how you use it.  You don't have to take my word for it, this has already been asked here before: [Is it correct to call an Apple Mac computer a PC (Personal Computer)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1022/is-it-correct-to-call-an-apple-mac-computer-a-pc-personal-computer)

> Not all PCs are Macs, but all Macs are PCs.
>
> [howtogeek.com](http://www.howtogeek.com/195224/macs-are-pcs-can-we-stop-pretending-they-arent/)

Anyway, here's how I'd word it:

> I am creating an app which is intended for use on PCs running unix, windows, or OSX.

Or more ambitiously:

> I am creating an app which is intended for use on PCs running any operating system.

If you can pull that off without fragmenting your code base I'd love to know how.  And don't say Java.

Comment: I think Apple resents having their products called "PC".

Comment: @HotLicks I'm sure they do.  They also resent having their iPhones called smart phones.  They want them called iPhones.  Doesn't stop them being smart phones.  "it's not a car it's a volkswagen" Yeah sure.  Branding is more important than reality.

Comment: A laptop may be someone's "personal computer," but there is a clear line between "laptop" and "PC."  A "PC" is generally considered to be a desktop computer and something different than a laptop.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman rather than bicker I'll just point you to my edits above.

Comment: @CandiedOragne : JEL hit the nail on the head.  There is a perceptual difference between what people call a "PC" and what people call a "personal computer."  While a laptop may be someone's "personal computer," a "PC" is always a desktop model.  For example, *Best Buy*'s current TV ad says, "All PCs and laptops are on sale."

Comment: It's all fine and dandy to slam Apple in this answer but the truth is there are PCs and Mac, and regardless of what's "under the hood" people differentiate between them.

Comment: @michael_timofeev : True that.  I had ignored the whole PC vs. Apple angle.  A PC is a desktop IBM compatible that can run Windows software, a desktop that is not an Apple.

Comment: @michael_timofeev I never claimed they didn't.  I only claimed the original meaning of PC isn't going away no matter how much money is spent to redefine it.  All it does is create another meaning.  I've tried to reflect that in my latest edit.

Comment: “When people say Mac vs. PC they're really saying Mac vs. Not Mac.” — I suspect when people say _Mac vs PC_, they’re really saying _Apple operating systems vs Windows_. Most people who care about the dichotomy don’t seem to consider Linux, BSD, Unix, Chrome OS, OS/2, BeOS, and many other OSes as entering into the equation at all.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet over a year ago, I not only considered Unix in my "how I'd word it" line, I gave it top billing.

Comment: “A Mac is a PC” sounds like an *alternative fact*.   :-)   ⁠

Comment: @scott I've already used Jel's input to update the question. Comments aren't meant to last.  I'll delete the ones that make no sense now.

Comment: This answer may be technically correct, but is totally unhelpful, sorry. If I use "PC" in a tech article/message, everyone who reads it will think of Windows computers only.

Comment: @lolmaus-AndreyMikhaylov that’s not true. I asked everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Probably **desktop** as compared to **mobile**

Comment: But Opie said "laptop".

Comment: In the development world "desktop" means not mobile- there is no difference in  developing code for a laptop and desktop PC.

Comment: "Desktop" means a non-portable computer.

Comment: So you buy separate "Laptop" versions of your PC software rather than the "desktop" version?

Comment: In the development world, the dichotomy between mobile and not-mobile does not exist. There are plenty of mobile devices that run OSes that can run the same code as non-mobile devices, and not all non-mobile devices can run the same code either. It doesn’t matter whether a device is mobile or not, but what type of code it is able to run.

Comment: As a software developer, I also use “desktop” to refer to any kind of PC (tower or laptop) and “mobile” to refer to smartphones, tablets, or even PDAs. However, this is apparently not typical outside the field. See for example “desktop publishing” or “desktop accounting” software.

Answer (score 1):

While smartphones and calculators are computers, native speakers don't generally put them in that category.  I can't speak for everyone, but for me a smartphone is a smartphone and a computer is a computer...they do different things and have different purposes.  A computer has more capability and can do many tasks and is more open to restructuring and reprogramming.  I think it's safe to use "computer" in your sentence.

Comment: For many years Macintosh computers were not open to restructuring and reprogramming.